# Using the log values vs linear values change the importance of features in Machine Learning (Random Forest)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am using a certain feature `(flux)` for which the values range from `1e-14` to `1e-11`. I am trying to use this feature along with many other features to predict two classes, A and B. The flux feature does discriminate between two features when I see the 2D plot, however, it shows `0` as the `feature importance` when I run the Random Forest Classifier. This can happen if the other features are more dominant.

If this flux is changed to its log value before training the data, the feature importance jumps to a high level. What could be the reason for this issue? Do I need to normalize/scale all my data before I train my classifier? I thought that the scaling is not needed in `decision tree based algorithms`. I would really appreciate for any help in this issue. Please note that the other features have values between 0 and 100.

Comment: I think your understanding is correct and monotonic transformations should not matter. What RF implementation are you using? It may simply be a numerical issue with those really small numbers. Given what you see, I would simply use the log-transformed values (and make sure you don't have any other values that are all super small [or super-big]).

Comment: @Björn, yes my values are extremely small for "flux" as I mentioned. It seems like the RF classifier (from sklearn python) is just assuming all these values as "0". I am still confused about the overall issue with a decision tree method requiring scaling here (logarithmic one in this case). Do you have any further comments or pointers or thoughts?

Comment: Could you be running into something as simple as round-off error?

Comment: @AdrianKeister, I don't think so. When I look at the parameter itself after loading it as a csv, it seems to display the exact values and I can get a histogram and plot against other parameters and it does work. The issue arises only when I run the classifier, it seems.